# Git: Synchronize not version controlled directory with a remote directory

Tags: git, merge

I have a copy of directory on cloud computer. Some files are changed there. This directory is not version controlled. How to synchronize / merge directory on cloud computer with `Github` remote repository? I want this cloud directory to be controlled by git afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet below should do it. The commands are:

- initializing new repository,
- adding all the files to be tracked by git,
- committing the changes to the local repository,
- adding remote from Github,
- pushing your local changes to Github.

```sh
git init
git add . 
git status # to ensure that you're adding the files that you're interested in
git commit -m "Start tracking directory state"
git remote add origin git@github.com://<user>/<repository>.git
git push origin master
```

This assumes that there is a connection between the server and the Github. Probably you'd also use ssh key to authenticate to remote repository (`git@github.com:/<user>/<repository>.git`), so the private key part needs to be also present on the server. The public key part needs to be added to Github.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer. Unfortunately this was not quite sufficient. I still had to solve the merge conflicts, because the directory was changed. Here are a few more steps to do so:

- pulling the files from `Github` for merging,
- show file with conflicts,
- adding all resolved files to mark them as merged,
- committing the changes to the local repository,
- pushing your local changes to Github.

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git status #show files with conflicts
#After resolving
#git checkout --ours file #use the local copy of file
git add .
git commit -m "Merge directory files with remote files"
git push origin master
```